# Basic calculator in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, calculator

I am a beginner in Python, I want to know if this code can be improved. Is it possible to make it work without the if/else?

```
number1=int(input('Enter first number: '))
number2=int(input('Enter Second number: '))
operation=input("Enter operation\n[+,-,*,/]")
if operation == '+':
    sum=number1+number2
elif operation == '-':
    sum =number1-number2
elif operation == '*':
    sum =number1*number2
else:
    sum =number1//number2
print(sum)
```

Comment: An immediate improvement would be not to use `sum` as a variable name since it shadows a builtin.

Comment: All operations except the last (`//`), I don't have a non-if/else solution for that. At least without resorting to `eval`, which should be avoided.

Comment: `sum =number1//number2`, sure this totally represent a sum.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't want any `if` statements then you can do the same with the [`operator` library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/operator.html) and a dictionary. This is by using the [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method that allows you to have a default value ([`operator.floordiv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.floordiv)) if the value isn't in the dictionary. After getting a valid function from the dictionary, you then just have to call the function.

```
import operator

operators = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul
}

number1 = int(input('Enter first number: '))
number2 = int(input('Enter Second number: '))
operation = input("Enter operation\n[+,-,*,/]")
print(operators.get(operation, operator.floordiv)(number1, number2))
```

I would however not assume division if the user enters random data. And so I'd add an `if` and `else`. In this case I'd check that the operator is in the `operators` dictionary, and perform the operation if it is. If it isn't, then I'd tell the user that they entered an invalid operator:

```
operators = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.floordiv
}

if operation in operators:
    print(operators[operation](number1, number2))
else:
    print('Invalid operator')
```

You can also make the operator list in the `input` automatically created from the dictionary too. To create the string `'+,-,*,/'` you can use [`','.join(['+', '-', '*', '/'])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), to get the array you can then use [`operators.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys). Finally you'd have to insert it into the rest of the string, and so I'd use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
operation = input("Enter operation\n[{}]".format(','.join(operators.keys())))
```

And so tying this all together you could use:

```
import operator

operators = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.floordiv
}

number1 = int(input('Enter first number: '))
number2 = int(input('Enter Second number: '))
operation = input("Enter operation\n[{}]".format(','.join(operators.keys())))
if operation in operators:
    print(operators[operation](number1, number2))
else:
    print('Invalid operator')
```

Comment: Adding to the conciseness, and in the spirit of teaching Python, there's also a chance here to use the ternary operator and Python's dynamic typing to change the last four lines to a single line:  `print(operators[operation](number1, number2) if operator in operations else "Invalid Operator")` This is basically equivalent to writing `print(operation in operators ? operators[operation](number1, number2) : 'Invalid Operator')` in a different language, but only works in a dynamically typed language like Python

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees Honestly, I find it hard to read. And so I personally wouldn't recommend it here.

Comment: The main goal was to introduce the ternary operator in Python, and so I do agree. Also, following the ["zen of python"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) `readability counts` and your code is more readable, but I sometimes prefer a one-liner print statement for conciseness because too many if statements can make the code be unreadable

Answer (score 7):

## `sum`

you use `sum` as a variable name, shadowing the builtin, which is generally a bad idea

## function

Divide the program into functions with their own goal. Here you have following part

1. get the 2 numbers
2. get the operation
3. do the calculation
4. present the result

## Get the numbers

you ask for an input, which you get returned as a `str`. You convert this to a number with `int`. If the input is not an integer value, this will crash the program, so you'll need some sort of input validation.

For the input validation, I will borrow a bit from [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/195399/123200) answer to another question

```
def ask_number(message='please enter a number', number_types=None):
    if number_types is None:
        number_types = (int, float, complex)
    while True:
        number = input(message)
        for converter in number_types:
            try:
                return converter(number)
            except ValueError:
                pass
        else:
            print('Please enter a valid number')
```

In this way, you can specify which types are valid, and in which order they should be tried. You can even use custom types if you want.

This will keep asking until you have a valid number, and can be stopped with `ctrl+c`, which will raise a `KeyboardInteruptError`

## Get the operation

To make it easy for ourselves, we define the default options for operators

```
DEFAULT_OPERATIONS = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '//': operator.floordiv,
    '/': operator.truediv,
    '**': operator.pow,
    '^': operator.pow,
}
```

This way we can call the function without arguments most of the times

```
def ask_operator(operators=None):
    if operators is None:
        operators = DEFAULT_OPERATIONS

    message = f'Please select an operator from [{','.join(map(str, operators)))}]'
    while True:
        operator = input(message)
        if operator in operators:
            return operator
        else:
            print('Please enter a valid operator')
```

## putting it together

```
def main():
    operators = DEFAULT_OPERATIONS

    number1 = ask_number('Please enter the first number:')
    number2 = ask_number('Please enter the second number:')
    operator_str = ask_operator(operators)
    operator = operators[operator_str]

    result = operator(number1, number2)

    print(f'{number1} {operator_str} {number2} = {result}')
```

which you can put behing a `if __name__ == '__main__'`-guard

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```